# How do I delete records in MySQL and keep the lastest date

Tags: mysql, sql

Example `table_1`

```
ID Email         Answer   UpdateDate
1  xxx.@xx.com   1        2011-07-02
2  xxx.@xx.com   3        2011-07-11
3  vvv.@xx.com   3        2011-07-12
4  vvv.@xx.com   5        2011-07-13
5  xxx.@xx.com   5        2011-07-14
6  xxx.@xx.com   4        2011-07-14
7  xxx.@xx.com   4        2011-07-14
8  zzz.@xx.com   4        2011-07-15
```

How do I delete this records but keep the latest `UpdateDate`

And the result :

```
ID Email         Answer   UpdateDate
4  vvv.@xx.com   5        2011-07-13
7  xxx.@xx.com   4        2011-07-14
8  zzz.@xx.com   4        2011-07-15
```

Comment: Well, that result wouldn't be right as far as the IDs go; IDs are not meant to change. The IDs in the result should be `5` and `4`.

Comment: Delan Azabani thanks for the IDs. Edited

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly you want to keep? Is it only the most recent date? The most recent for each email address? the most recent for each Answer value? Or something else?

Comment: @Steve Claridge I want to delete all duplicate `Email` addresses but keep only one according to latest `UpdateDate`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a temporary variable to store the highest date and then a seperate query to delete everything that is < than that. Remember that variables are connection specific.

```
select max(UpdateDate) from table_1 into @TempUpdateDate

delete from table_1 where UpdateDate < @TempUpdateDate
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.. This one is working but some data will delete without keep the latest date.

Comment: This still has the same kind of logical error as the other answer.  Each email address needs to keep the latest record for *that* email address.  As each email address has a different date in it's last email address, you can't use a temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

I'd check the UpdateDate against a correlated sub-query.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
  latestRecord (
    Email        VARCHAR(128),
    updateDate   DATETIME
) 
INSERT INTO 
  latestRecord
SELECT
  Email,
  MAX(updateDate) AS updateDate
FROM
  table_1
GROUP BY
  Emal

DELETE 
  table_1
FROM
  table_1
INNER JOIN
  latestRecord
    ON  latestRecord.Email      = table_1.Email
    AND latestRecord.updateDate < table_1.updateDate
```

**EDIT**

Another refactor of the same logic

Comment: Missed the "FROM" on the top line.

Comment: You can't specify target table 'table_1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Another refactor using a temporary table.  Apparently MySQL doesn't a table to be DELETEd or UPDATEd and also be used in a sub-query.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure UpdateDate is a DATETIME field.

Do you want to keep the latest UpdateDate for each Answer value? This would do that:

```
delete from table_1 where UpdateDate not in ( select max(UpdateDate) from table_1 group by Answer );
```

if you only want to keep the latest date then:

```
delete from table_1 where UpdateDate not in ( select max(UpdateDate) from table_1 );
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. I got  1093 - You can't specify target table 'table_1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: He wants the latest answer per user (email address).  The use on `NOT IN` won't work here, as each user will only have one date to be kept, and it will likely be different between users.  (I'll look at this syntax problem too.)